# PhpStorm running HTML inspection on React/JSX component

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have the "*Missing required 'title' element*" inspection enabled under *Editor > Inspections > HTML > Accessibility*.

However, PhpStorm (currently on v2021.2) doesn't seem to know the difference between a React element (`<Head />`) and a regular HTML element (`<head></head>`) in this case:

[image]

This is inside of a `.tsx` file. Is there a way to ensure this inspection only runs on actual HTML elements instead of React elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow [WEB-52091](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52091) for updates.
For now, I can only suggest suppressing the inspection for file by adding

```
// noinspection HtmlRequiredTitleElement
```

at the top of it;

Or, you can create a custom scope in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes** with only `.html` files included and specify this scope for **HTML | Accessibility | Missing required 'title' element** inspection

Comment: For now, I've re-named the `Head` component to something else and that works for me. Thanks for the link to that issue in TY!